# C++ dynamic object class comparison

Tags: c++

I want to be able to compare syntax trees for expressions. The base class `Expr` has a pure virtual `compare` method for concrete subclasses to override:

```
class Expr {
public:
  virtual bool compare(const Expr *other) const = 0;
};
```

As an example, say `NumExpr` and `AddExpr` are two concrete subclasses for representing a literal integer expression and a binary add expression respectively. The first thing each `compare` method does is use `dynamic_cast` to make sure the `other` expression is of the same type:

```
class NumExpr : public Expr {
  int num;
public:
  NumExpr(int n) : num(n) {}
  bool compare(const Expr *other) const {
    const NumExpr *e = dynamic_cast<const NumExpr*>(other);
    if (e == 0) return false;
    return num == e->num;
  }
};

class AddExpr : public Expr {
  Expr *left, *right;
public:
  AddExpr(Expr *l, Expr *r) : left(l), right(r) {}
  bool compare(const Expr *other) const {
    const AddExpr *e = dynamic_cast<const AddExpr*>(other);
    if (e == 0) return false;
    return left->compare(e->left) && right->compare(e->right);
  }
};
```

I always feel like I am doing something wrong when I use `dynamic_cast` -- 
is there a more appropriate approach to perform dynamic comparisons between objects
without using `dynamic_cast`?

Using the [visitor design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) does *not* solve the need for RTTI (as far as I can tell). The abstract base class for an "expression visitor" might look something like this:

```
class NumExpr;
class AddExpr;

class ExprVisitor {
public:
  virtual void visit(NumExpr *e) {}; // "do nothing" default
  virtual void visit(AddExpr *e) {};
};
```

The base class for expressions includes a pure virtual `accept` method:

```
class Expr {
public:
  virtual void accept(ExprVisitor& v) = 0;
};
```

The concrete expression subclasses then use **double dispatch** to invoke the appropriate `visit` method:

```
class NumExpr : public Expr {
public:
  int num;
  NumExpr(int n) : num(n) {}
  virtual void accept(ExprVisitor& v) {
    v.visit(this);
  };
};

class AddExpr : public Expr {
public:
  Expr *left, *right;
  AddExpr(Expr *l, Expr *r) : left(l), right(r) {}
  virtual void accept(ExprVisitor& v) {
    v.visit(this);
  };
};
```

When we finally get to performing the expression comparisons using this mechanism, we *still* need to use RTTI (as far as I can tell); For example,  here is a sample visitor class for comparing expressions:

```
class ExprCompareVisitor : public ExprVisitor {
  Expr *expr;
  bool result;
public:
  ExprCompareVisitor(Expr *e) : expr(e), result(false) {}
  bool getResult() const {return result;}

  virtual void visit(NumExpr *e) {
    NumExpr *other = dynamic_cast<NumExpr *>(expr);
    result = other != 0 && other->num == e->num;
  }

  virtual void visit(AddExpr *e) {
    AddExpr *other = dynamic_cast<AddExpr *>(expr);
    if (other == 0) return;

    ExprCompareVisitor vleft(other->left);
    e->left->accept(vleft);
    if (!vleft.getResult()) return;

    ExprCompareVisitor vright(other->right);
    e->right->accept(vright);
    result = vright.getResult();
  }
};
```

Note we are still using RTTI (`dynamic_cast` is this case).

If we truly wish to avoid RTTI we could "roll our own" be creating unique constants to identify every concrete expression flavor:

```
enum ExprFlavor {
  NUM_EXPR, ADD_EXPR
};

class Expr {
public:
  const ExprFlavor flavor;
  Expr(ExprFlavor f) : flavor(f) {}
  ...
};
```

Each concrete type would set this constant appropriately:

```
class NumExpr : public Expr {
public:
  int num;
  NumExpr(int n) : Expr(NUM_EXPR), num(n) {}
  ...
};

class AddExpr : public Expr {
public:
  Expr *left, *right;
  AddExpr(Expr *l, Expr *r) : Expr(ADD_EXPR), left(l), right(r) {}
  ...
};
```

Then we could use `static_cast` and the `flavor` field to avoid RTTI:

```
class ExprCompareVisitor : public ExprVisitor {
  Expr *expr;
  bool result;
public:
  ExprCompareVisitor(Expr *e) : expr(e), result(false) {}
  bool getResult() const {return result;}

  virtual void visit(NumExpr *e) {                                                                
    result = expr->flavor == NUM_EXPR && static_cast<NumExpr *>(expr)->num == e->num;
  }
  ...
};
```

This solution seems like I am just replicating what the RTTI is doing under the hood.

Comment: Look up **double dispatch**.

Comment: Or the visitor design pattern.

Comment: is it right that the compare function returns true if the `underlying expressions are the same` and returns false in every other case... ?

Comment: Yes. This is used to convert a syntax tree into a syntax DAG by recognizing common subtrees in the expression. e.g. (3 + x)*2 + (3 + x)/2 would only represent 3 + x once.

Comment: Thanks for the tips on using the **visitor design pattern** and **double dispatch** seeing that this makes a lot of sense for syntax trees for compilers (as described in [these UW compiler course notes](http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse582/02au/lectures/slides/3up/h-ASTs-3up.pdf)). OTOH, it does *not* solve the original problem, since the `visit` methods still need to perform some sort of RTTI to determine if two expressions are of the same type. I think this is a good example where RTTI is OK.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you don't know the dynamic type of either side at compile time (for example the static type is the same as the dynamic type) and that you in fact want to compare two `Expr` objects by pointer or reference, then you are going to have to make two virtual calls (double dispatch) or use `dynamic_cast`.

It would look something like this:

```
class Expr {
public:
  virtual bool compare(const Expr *other) const = 0;
  virtual bool compare(const NumExpr *other) const { return false; }
  virtual bool compare(const AddExpr *other) const {return false;}
};

class NumExpr : public Expr {
  int num;
public:
  explicit NumExpr(int n) : num(n) {}
  bool compare(const Expr *other) const {
    return other->compare(this);
  }
  bool compare(const NumExpr *other) const {
    return num == other->num;
  }
};
```

Comment: this particular solution requires that the `Expr` be aware of all derived types like `NumExpr` before hand... would require a `forward declaration` in the code... one would not be able to add new expressions without changing the code for mother `Expr`...

Comment: This certainly avoids the `dynamic_cast`, but becomes unwieldy when there are a numerous subclasses and subverts the reason to form a class hierarchy in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

There is the `typeid Operator` that can be used instead of `dynamic_cast` for the initial type matching.

[(src)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/typeinfo/type_info/)

Comment: Really just the same approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RTTI.

```
class NumExpr : public Expr {
  int num;
public:
   NumExpr(int n) : num(n) {}
bool compare(const Expr *other) const {
if ( typeid(*other) != typeid(*this) )
     return false;
 else {
     NumExpr *e = static_cast<NumExpr*>(other);
     return num == e->num;
  }
  }
};
```

Comment: What is `e`? Doesn't compile,

Comment: Using `typeid` and `static_cast` not really different than using `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: One difference between `typeid` and `dynamic_cast` is that `dynamic_cast` can find a subobject anywhere in the inheritance tree, but `typeid` will only tell you the most-derived type.  So for most purposes, `typeid` is even worse than `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: Yes aschepler, dynamic_cast will succeed for a base type although the actual object is a subtype. So in the above code, if other is a subtype of NumExpr, say NumExprSpecial,  dynamic_cast <const NumExpr*>(other) will succeed and an instance of NumExprSpecial and an instance of NumExpr may end up being equal. Unless that makes sense to your application?, typeid is a better solution.